# Predict Panel Data Model values with a LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, lstm, panel-data

I want to **make predictions** of how many mail postards are sent daily in every post office in my city. The problem seems easy, but I want to predict how many postcards are **sent in each office** and **what type the postcards are**.

```
Post Offices = [001, 002, 003]
Postcards Types = [A, B, C]
Prediction target = 'Amount'
```

An example of the data I have:

```
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| Date                 | Post office | Postcard type | Amount | Other vairables... |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 001         | A             | 23     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 001         | B             | 1      |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 001         | C             | 15     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 002         | A             | 44     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 002         | B             | 6      |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 002         | C             | 29     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 003         | A             | 15     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 003         | B             | 1      |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-01           | 003         | C             | 10     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-02           | 001         | A             | 25     |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| 2023-01-02           | 001         | B             | 3      |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
| Rest of reigsters... |             |               |        |                    |
+----------------------+-------------+---------------+--------+--------------------+
```

I have worked with LSTM network but I don't know how to aproach this problem with an LSTM to generate one unique model. I have been searching but cant find a way of solving the problem because the model should predict the *Amount* for each office and each type (categorical variables). The model should distict that *office 002* has much more traffic than *office 001*. My data is a **Panel Data Model** and there is not much information about this on the internet.

**As a bonus**:
If anyone gets the solution, is there a way of automating this process of classification by categorical values? Imagine that I have a new variable "Delivery success" with values ["Delivery OK", "Delivery failure"] so that I can group them by ("Date", "Post office", "Postcard type" and "Delivery success"). How canI make a model that supports this feature?

Comment: You can search about multivariate time series forecasting, there are quite lots of publications toward this.

Comment: @MinhNguyenHoang I am looking more into a Panel Data Model problem

Comment: As I see, if you have 3 `Post Offices` and 3 `Postcards Types`, then you can have a total of `3x3 = 9` time series, which you can then use a multivariate models to forecast.